# PostgreSQL: Query has no destination for result data in a query with variables

Tags: postgresql

ERROR:  query has no destination for result data

HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 11 at SQL statement

````
DO $$
DECLARE
id_renovacion integer := (select Id_renovacionContrato 
from BEA.DIM_RENOVACION_CONTRATO where upper(Desc_renovacionContrato) = 'UNDEFINED'); 

id_renovacionpending integer := (select Id_renovacionContrato 
from BEA.DIM_RENOVACION_CONTRATO where upper(Desc_renovacionContrato) = 'PENDING');


BEGIN

SELECT count(id_contrato) as id_cantidad,
                CASE    when count(id_contrato) = 0 THEN 'ImagesHappyMaritransparente1.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) is null THEN 'ImagesHappyMaritransparente1.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 1 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-1_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 2 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-2_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 3 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-3_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 4 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-4_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 5 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-5_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 6 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-6_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 7 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-7_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 8 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-8_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 9 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-9_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) > 9 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-9+_145.png'
                END
 FROM BEA.FACT_CONTRATOS
WHERE cantDiasDif > 0 AND Id_rangoContrato IN (id_renovacion, id_renovacionpending);

END 
$$

LANGUAGE plpgsql; ```
````

Comment: The error message is quite descriptive. Do you understand what is says? What did you plan to do with the selected data?

Comment: what is your question? "How do you avoid: ```ERROR: query has no destination for result data```" ?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems I can see in the posted code.

1. `create` in the code. I am not sure why do you have `create` in your anonymous block.
2. You have the following SELECT in your DO block:

```
SELECT count(id_contrato) as id_cantidad,
                CASE    when count(id_contrato) = 0 THEN 'ImagesHappyMaritransparente1.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) is null THEN 'ImagesHappyMaritransparente1.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 1 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-1_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 2 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-2_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 3 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-3_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 4 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-4_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 5 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-5_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 6 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-6_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 7 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-7_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 8 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-8_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 9 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-9_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) > 9 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-9+_145.png'
                END
 FROM BEA.FACT_CONTRATOS
WHERE cantDiasDif > 0 AND Id_rangoContrato IN (id_renovacion, id_renovacionpending);
```

And you are not storing the returned result of the SELECT into any variable. If you don't care of the SELECT result, then use PERFORM as given below:

```
PERFORM count(id_contrato) as id_cantidad,
                CASE    when count(id_contrato) = 0 THEN 'ImagesHappyMaritransparente1.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) is null THEN 'ImagesHappyMaritransparente1.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 1 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-1_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 2 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-2_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 3 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-3_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 4 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-4_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 5 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-5_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 6 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-6_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 7 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-7_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 8 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-8_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 9 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-9_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) > 9 THEN 'ImagesTITIhappymarycontratos-off-9+_145.png'
                END
 FROM BEA.FACT_CONTRATOS
WHERE cantDiasDif > 0 AND Id_rangoContrato IN (id_renovacion, id_renovacionpending);
```

However, question why do you want to do that? Let us know the reason for not storing the result of the SELECT or your intention.

Comment: Hi Vibhor, yes you are right, that "create" is a mistake in the code, i'm trying to solve it creating a table and I solve it. additionally I applied your recommendation adding a PERFORM instead of SELECT in the code, but I need the result to be shown, which with CREATE was solved. Answering your question I am using this to display it in a BI application: MicroStrategy. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

This code solve the problem, use a CREATE table to show results.

````
DO $$
DECLARE
id_renovacion integer := (select Id_renovacionContrato 
from BEA.DIM_RENOVACION_CONTRATO where upper(Desc_renovacionContrato) = 'UNDEFINED'); 

id_renovacionpending integer := (select Id_renovacionContrato 
from BEA.DIM_RENOVACION_CONTRATO where upper(Desc_renovacionContrato) = 'PENDING');


BEGIN

DROP TABLE if EXISTS  tbcontratos;
CREATE TABLE tbcontratos (id_cantidad integer, images varchar(200));

insert into tbcontratos
SELECT count(id_contrato) as id_cantidad,
                CASE    when count(id_contrato) = 0 THEN 'Images\HappyMari\transparente1.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) is null THEN 'Images\HappyMari\transparente1.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 1 THEN 'Images\TITI\happymary\contratos-off-1_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 2 THEN 'Images\TITI\happymary\contratos-off-2_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 3 THEN 'Images\TITI\happymary\contratos-off-3_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 4 THEN 'Images\TITI\happymary\contratos-off-4_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 5 THEN 'Images\TITI\happymary\contratos-off-5_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 6 THEN 'Images\TITI\happymary\contratos-off-6_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 7 THEN 'Images\TITI\happymary\contratos-off-7_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 8 THEN 'Images\TITI\happymary\contratos-off-8_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) = 9 THEN 'Images\TITI\happymary\contratos-off-9_145.png'
                             when count(id_contrato) > 9 THEN 'Images\TITI\happymary\contratos-off-9+_145.png'
                END
 FROM BEA.FACT_CONTRATOS
WHERE cantDiasDif > 0 AND Id_rangoContrato IN (id_renovacion, id_renovacionpending);



END 
$$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select id_cantidad, images from tbcontratos; ```
````